# Single floating gate transistor

Tags: flash

On a previous question I just asked it was about storing an led's previous state with the eeprom. Without a microcontroller, it seemed not possible, so now Im asking if you can buy single floating gate transistors anywhere, because I have searched, and nothing showed up. Do they even make this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy a normal FET, leave the gate unconnected. You now have a floating gate transistor :)

Less flippantly, this is actually one of the answers suggested to your previous question: connect a capacitor to the gate of a FET with some way of charging and discharging it. If you design the circuit to minimise the current leakage off the capacitor and use a large capacitor, you can store a bit for a long time.

Comment: Only if its a MOSFET ... a JFET gate probably doesn't float freely enough. But ... :-)

Comment: wow I am here 10 years later does this actually work?