# How to implement a solid-state non-volatile switch?

Tags: mosfet, switches, solid-state-relay, toggle-switch, non-volatile-memory

I found [this heavily downvoted question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343611/non-volatile-switches) about how to  implement a non-volatile switch (i.e. a switch that remembers its last state even when power is removed).  While the OP asked the question in a weird way, attempting to incorporate chemical processes, I am simply interested in creating a solid-state switch that remembers its last state when power is removed.

I understand that this feature can be easily achieved with an impulse/latching relay. However, I am seeking to implement the switch without any mechanical components (fully solid-state).

The helpful respondent Dave Tweed stated that floating gate MOSFETs can be used to achieve this feature, much like flash memory is implemented.  However, I am having a hard time finding actual schematics showing such a circuit.

I found "latching SSRs" but these appear to only hold the state while power is applied. Once load power is removed, it appears they go back to the default "OFF" state.

I am looking for the following switch characteristics:

- Switches 24VDC up to 5 amps.
- Momentary input pushbutton toggles switch state with each press.
- Switch resumes last state when power is removed and restored (no time limit).
- No microcontroller required
- Bonus feature: the ability to toggle the switch with a low voltage pulsed input (i.e. 3.3VDC from a microcontroller)

I would be grateful for any pointers toward schematics or examples.

[Here](https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/nonvolatile-standbyon-switch.html) is a design note from 2009 for such a switch.  Note how complex this is, in relation to a mechanical latching relay, and also that there are a limited number of power cycles before the memory wears out (50,000 minimum), whereas a relay can easily exceed 1 million cycles.

Comment: You're not going to be able to turn an FGMOS on or off with 3.3 V. FGMOS devices usually require much higher voltages to program (generated on-chip for most ((E)E)PROMs today, but old ones required a programming supply of somewhere in the vicinity of 15 to 20 V). You need to induce Fowler-Nordheim tunnelling through the gate oxide to get charges to the floating gate, and that requires much higher voltages than you normally use for logic devices.

Comment: @Hearth ok so that blows out my bonus feature... but can it be done with the 24V supply without needing a microcontroller?  i.e. with just a momentary pushbutton that toggles the switch on and off?

Comment: Please do not edit a question after it's been answered in such a way as to invalidate existing answers; I'm pretty sure that's against site rules.

Comment: @Hearth, again apologies but I added this info before I saw your response, as I wanted to make the question more clear and avoid wasting people's time responding with "latching mechanical relay" answers.  My original intent was "solid-state" but I failed to make that clear - thus the modification.  Apparently I modified it too late, sorry about that.  I have now modified the title to include "solid-state" to ensure the question is more clear.

Comment: Can I what it's for?  If just an academic exercise the solid-state nonvolatility is intereting: perhaps you could use some form of [e-paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper), then photosensors.  In real life, use a microcontroller with built-in flash or a latching relay.

Comment: @RyanGriggs you need a physical bistable state. Core memory requires a very peculiar type of hysteresis. And such cores are more difficult to find today. But they are very fast and would work. For a modern design you may be on your own, though.

Comment: Is there a reason power can't be included e.g. a coin cell to run a basic logic circuit? (Regarding "solid state", note there are ceramic batteries available these days, a technicality I would gladly [ab]use.)

Comment: @RyanGriggs If you do decide to learn and push though something like a core memory cell (single tiny toroid) then look up *square loop ferrites* as a keyword/phrase. They are still being sold. You may also want to skim [this paper at NASA's site](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19670003661/downloads/19670003661.pdf) for a long discussion about how to understand and then design around them. Like others, I may use an MCU -- selecting an FRAM MCU if things need to be fast (microsecond or faster) or anything with NV EEROM or FLASH if okay with multiple millisecond timings.

Comment: @everyone - The idea came from seeing a small, cheap LED strip controller that uses momentary pushbutton for On/Off.  The controller remembers its last power state, even after being unplugged and re-plugged.  It's likely they are using a tiny MCU with flash memory to do this, but it got me thinking if the same thing was possible without the MCU just using individual MOSFET and passives.  I realize that FLASH memory wears out after some number of writes.  FRAM is durable and fast but was hoping to learn by making the entire circuit very simple without ICs.  Did not realize this was difficult.

Comment: @everyone - It's very interesting to consider that this problem is easily solved with a mechanical latching relay but requires quite a bit more engineering (MCU, FRAM, etc) to do it with solid state components.

Comment: @RyanGriggs perhaps [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/50124/173919) helps?  For a non-mosfet technique: magnetise or degauss a piece of steel; measure with Hall-effector sensor?

Comment: @jonathanjo Can you clarify the floating gate MOSFET technique? Is the Gate pin simply left disconnected during float, otherwise shorted to +V or GND to turn the circuit on/off?  How long would it hold this floating charge in such a state?

Comment: How long does the circuit have to hold its last state?

Comment: @AnalogKid I would prefer "days" or "weeks".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking for quite a bit there, for one thing "no time limit" is going to have to be quantified, as nothing lasts forever.

One possible solution is using programmable voltage references as memory as shown in [this article](https://www.analog.com/en/design-notes/nonvolatile-standbyon-switch.html), the basic idea is it's set on or off by programming the voltage reference high or low, then when power is removed it retains the last programmed state.

There's a limit to how long something like this will work though as they can only be reprogrammed a limited number of times, but the article states a minimum of 50,000 so it may be enough depending on your application.

Comment: Whoops, I saw your link after posting the same one as an update to my question :D   The limitation of 50,000 cycles is what bothers me, whereas a relay can achieve millions of cycles without problems.   I did not realize this type of solid-state switch was so difficult to achieve in relation to adding a latching relay to the system!  Thanks for this info.

Comment: I think this solution is the closest to what I had in mind, although I was hoping for something much simpler (i.e a MOSFET and some passives).  Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this doesn't use an FGMOS at all, but simply an electromechanical device known as a latching relay.

Most relays are not latching, and use a spring to return the contacts to the initial position when coil power is removed. But latching relays latch into either state just like a lightswitch.

They come in one-coil and two-coil versions, where the one-coil type needs a positive coil voltage to actuate and a negative coil voltage to reset, and the two-coil type actuates with a pulse on one coil and resets with a pulse on the other. You could probably arrange a handful of logic gates and a 555 or two to convert sequential pulses into alternating pulses to the set and reset coils. I'll leave that as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: This is the answer.... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay#Latching_relay

Comment: Apologies for the confusion: I modified my question apparently while you were writing this response. I would like to create a true "latching" relay but without mechanical components (solid-state only).  I understand that this would be easy to achieve with an electro-mechanical latching relay, but I am interested in a fully solid-state solution.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/50124/173919) suggests: **connect a capacitor to the gate of a FET with some way of charging and discharging it**

My understanding is that you basically set up something like this.  In real life the switches would likely to be mosfets.  You have to organise it so that the capacitor leaks as little charge as possible, through the mosfet or anywhere else. You might consider having a pair of capacitors and use a comparator, not a level-sense.

The devil will certainly be in the detail!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6EWXC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This looks promising. If C1 leakage could be minimized may we achieve at least "days" or "weeks" of hold time? Also I need the momentary pushbutton SW2 to toggle the output on or off with each press.  This particular circuit would require toggling SW1, then pressing SW2 in order to toggle the output state.

Comment: @RyanGriggs This was intended to be explanatory of the concept, no more.  SW1 and SW2 would be replaced by whatever is convenient.  Keeping charge for a week is certainly possible, but these kinds of sensitive circuits are not my area of expertise.  I'd use an ATTiny  or similar, 8 pins, £0.40.